# Cannot user VPN Pulse after Ventura OS Update

Tags: security, vpn, ventura

After updating macOS Catalina to macOS Ventura 13.0 (22A380) I cannot user Pulse Secure VPN Client (9.1.13 (11723)) anymore.

I am getting following error:

```
Xprotect 13.0 does not comply with policy. Compliance requires real time protection enabled.
```

And the in another window of Pulse Secure I get:

```
Wait    Connection Error

Endpoint is out of compliance. (Error:1122) 

Access was refused because your system does not meet security requirements. Some issues can be fixed automatically, and then you can try the login again. For other issues, please click the link to see the actions you can take to resolve the issue.
```

How I tag get rid of that?

Comment: Historically pulse secure (now under Ivanti) isn't immediately supported on new macOS releases.

Comment: I created a new post on the PulseSecure community:
https://community.pulsesecure.net/t5/Pulse-Connect-Secure/Cannot-user-VPN-Pulse-after-Ventura-OS-Update/m-p/47808#M30232

Comment: I have a Macbook Pro 14-inch with macOS Ventura. I have the same version of Pulse Secure as yours. I got an error likes. "Failed to connect to the Pulse Secure service" when adding a new connection. I tried the command ```sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/net.pulsesecure.AccessService.plist``` and it works fine now!

Comment: @kitsune any luck to resolve the issue ?

Comment: https://my.pulsesecure.net/ 
Pulse Secure Client renamed to Ivanti Secure Access Client & versioning changed from 9.1rx to 22.2R1 from the July 22 Release.

Comment: Maybe you can try the latest version here https://vubnet.vub.ac.be/downloads.html or https://umanitoba.ca/computing/ist/connect/vpnmac.html. I found them on google and it works fine on my Macbook Pro M1 14 inch with Macos Ventura

Comment: I can confirm this is not an issue related to a version of Pulse Client nether to the compliance requirements set server-side. I just solved by simply running `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/net.pulsesecure.AccessService.plist`. I suppose this issue affects only those users who "migrated" from previous versions of macOS to the new Ventura v13.

Comment: @ThachHuynh you can post your answer here and I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I've posted my answer. Thank you @kitsune!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same version of Pulse Secure as yours and also upgraded to Macos Ventura on my Macbook pro 14 inch M1.

I got an error likes: `Failed to connect to the Pulse Secure service` when adding a new connection. I tried the command `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/net.pulsesecure.AccessService.plist` and it works fine now!

==============================================

Another solution:

As Pulse Secure announced here https://my.pulsesecure.net/:

> Pulse Secure Software 9.1R16 is now released (July 19th, 2022).
>
> KB45301 - Pulse Secure Client renamed to Ivanti Secure Access Client &
> versioning changed from 9.1rx to 22.2R1 from the July 22 Release.

I found a link where you can download the Ivanti Secure Access Client https://vubnet.vub.ac.be/downloads.html.

It works well without the need to run any extra commands!